# Spotify property returns anonymous function

Tags: spotify, javascript-automation

running the following code in Script Editor

```
app = Application('Spotify');
app.soundVolume
```

returns

```
[function anonymous] {
  "name":"", 
  "prototype":{"constructor":[function anonymous]}
}
```

instead of an integer value. If I try to run the function the Script Editor stops me with the error:

> Error: Message not understood

Comment: got stuck on the same problem, maybe their API is not yet compatible with JXA

Comment: @mateusmaso You mean JXA is not compatible with Spotify. AppleScript is—and always has been—the de facto standard against which **all** scriptable apps are developed and tested. When JXA falls over on tasks that work perfectly well in AppleScript, that's a design defect or bug in JXA for failing to follow that spec. During the 10.10 beta I found so many I gave up sending bug reports and just sent the AS team a [working JavaScriptOSA implementation](http://sourceforge.net/projects/appscript/files) to copy from instead, but they ignored it and shipped their own broken version…to everyone's loss.

Comment: @foo good and sad to know hahah, it really seems to be a bad bridge between AS spec to JXA spec.. let's wait until they fix it

Comment: Would be very interested to know if this has been overcome. Not sure why it has a JavaScript dictionary if none of the functions actually work.